# How to avoid set method when assign the value in swift？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In objective-c we can use `self.foo = xxx` to call `-setFoo:` method and use `_foo = xxx` to avoid it.

But how can we avoid set when using Swift?

I doing it like this.

```
// use foo = xxx to call set
public var foo: Int {
    set {
        fooInside = newValue
        // ...
        bar()
    }
    get { return fooInside }
}
// use fooInside = xxx to avoid set
private var fooInside = 0
```

Do we have a more elegant way? Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand your question here but I think you should take a look at willSet and didSet

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry, I'm pool in English. :(

Comment: I think what you're doing is the exact equivalent of the Objective-C pattern. Just rename `fooInside` to `_foo` and there you have it.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe Good suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think extension is elegant to do this:

```
extension Int {
    mutating func setValue(value: Int,update: Bool) {
        self = value
        if update {

        }
    }
}
```